# unable to boot porteus linux using bootloader

Tags: linux, boot, grub, bootloader

I have been using porteus on my card and using *syslinux* bootloader to boot it. I tried to install grub installer using *grub.txz* file as per the official porteus installation on another usb card.
For that I installed *grub.txz* file onto my existing porteus as per the following link,

http://www.porteus.org/tutorials/12-boot-loaders/71-install-grub-to-usb-drive.html

but, upon starting system, I am getting error like " [syslinux] USB boot: No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!" and " Could not find kernel image".

Also all my previous *syslinux* files and porteus folder got deleted including *.iso* file. I am just having '*ldlinux.sys*' file inside *boot/syslinux* directory.

Please help , if I can get all my files back and boot porteus again. Also help me with some bootloader commands, if any!

[image: Error message]

Comment: Hey, I've already asked you not to use irrelevant tasks on your other question. I'm removing [ubuntu] from this one too. Please don't clutter the site.

Comment: hi..nothing irrelevant I see here as Sometimes ubuntu has the similar problems, So I was just hoping to get relevant answers using it.

Comment: Your problem is _very_ specific to Porteus. Ubuntu comes with GRUB out of the box, the installer installs it and configures it for you - so nobody using Ubuntu will face these issues when switching from syslinux to GRUB.